# CakePhp esta ignorando meu model

Tags: cakephp

Tenho um plugin "Admin" e nele tenho o seguinte: UsersController.php (UsersController), User.php (é o Model User).
Neste meu caso, estou salvando dados de usuário, o controller salva corretamente os dados, estretanto as funções de validação, criptografia de senha e qualquer outra que coloquei no controller, até mesmo para teste, não carregam. Segue a baixo:

UsersController.php (UsersController) ---

```
class UsersController extends AdminAppController {

    public $name = 'Users';
    var $helpers = array('Form', 'Html');

    public function index() {
        $name =  $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();

            if(isset($this->data)){
            $this->User->set($this->data); 
                if ($this->User->validates()){
                    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                          $this -> Session -> setFlash('Usuario cadastrado!');
                          $this -> Redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                          exit();
                    } else {
                        $this -> Session -> setFlash('Nao foi possível, cadastrar usuario. Por favir aguarde!');
                        $this -> Redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                        exit();                
                    }
                }
                else{
                     $this -> Session -> setFlash($this->User->invalidFields());
                     $this -> Redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
                     exit();                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

User.php (é o Model User) ---

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

   public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Nome obrigatorio'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Senha Obrigatoria'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'E-mail obrigatorio'
        ),
        'group_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Grupo obrigatorio'
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Tabela no bando de dados é users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu model esta dentro do plugin?

Se tiver tente usar no controler:

```
public $uses = array(
    'Admin.User',
);
```

Se nao tiver no plugin use:

```
public $uses = array(
    'User',
);
```

Faca essas chamadas antes do das chamadas do Helper no seu controller.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado, resolveu o meu problema. O que eu não entendi, foi o motivo de não estar funcionando sem adicionar isso no controler, pois segundo o que li na documentação do CakePHP, se seguir as convenções de nome, essa parte deveria ser "automática", e deixar essas coisas "automáticas" é o principal motivo de seguir as convenções. Mas felizmente esta funcionando agora, mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Então charles, provavelmente o que aconteceu, é que o  seu Modelo, está na raiz do projeto, e o seu Controller está no plugin Admin. Quando é assim, o controller do plugin não herda pelo nome o model da raiz. Quando os dois estão no mesmo plugin, ou na raiz do projeto, por convenção do cakephp, não é necessário usar o $uses quando os dois tem o mesmo nome, model = singular, controller = plural.